how can i use langchain's conversationchain?
if 'conversation_memory' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.conversation_memory = ConversationBufferMemory(human_prefix="user", ai_prefix="ai")

memory = st.session_state.conversation_memory

conversation = ConversationChain(memory=memory, llm = RemoteRunnable(LANGSERVE_ENDPOINT))

if user_input := st.chat_input():
    add_history("user", user_input)
    st.chat_message("user").write(user_input)
    with st.chat_message("assistant"):
        
        chat_container = st.empty()
        
        if file is not None:
            prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(RAG_PROMPT_TEMPLATE)

            rag_chain = (
                {
                    "context": retriever | format_docs,
                    "question": RunnablePassthrough(),
                }
                | prompt
                | conversation.llm
                | StrOutputParser()
            )
            answer = rag_chain.stream(user_input)  
            chunks = []
            for chunk in answer:
                chunks.append(chunk)
                chat_container.markdown("".join(chunks))
            conversation.memory.save_context(inputs={"user": user_input}, outputs={"ai": "".join(chunks)})
            add_history("ai", "".join(chunks))
            
            
        else:
            prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(
                "please answer briefly :\n{input}"
            )

            chain = prompt | conversation.llm | StrOutputParser()
            answer = chain.stream(user_input)  
            chunks = []
            for chunk in answer:
                chunks.append(chunk)
                chat_container.markdown("".join(chunks))
            conversation.memory.save_context(inputs={"user": user_input}, outputs={"ai": "".join(chunks)})
            add_history("ai", "".join(chunks))


I made code with streamlit, I've seen in the code that the previous conversations are stored in memory, but it's not actually being applied. How can I do that?
I want to put conversationchain in the chain part but this is not working. Please tell me how to do this
